# User access to every collection they didn't create

Tags: content-management, role-management, content-hub

I want to make users add User access to every collection they didn't create without manually assigning them as Manager.
I have a user group for the users and added a Manager Role privilege but I'm getting errors.

Is this possible in the Content hub? If so, did I miss some configurations?

[image]

Comment: Did you try logout and login again?

Comment: Hello, yes we still have the same scenario.